How GHC captures the enviroment of variables when lambda expressions are used by value or by reference?
In this stackoverflow post there is code in C++ that tries to mimic associated types. When the lambda functions capture the environment(closure) using by reference capture the code compiles but fails at runtime. When the code changed to capture by value the code succeeds both at compile time and runtime. How GHC captures the closure of a lambda function, by reference or by value?

The first answer to this is: You shouldn't care. Haskell is about expressing what you want as something like a mathematical expression and letting the compiler/runtime do the work of figuring out how to most efficiently evaluate it. You can imagine though, that without optimizations everything is by-reference, never by value. The reason you don't have the same problem as your C++ code though, is because Haskell has a garbage collector, which figures out when it's safe to free things from memory. In C++ there is no garbage collector; you have to be careful about things going out of scope.

Haskell uses garbage collection: https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Memory_Management

In Haskell everything is immutable, and there is no way to distinguish a copy from the "original" value. Therefore capturing by value or by reference make no difference, and could be regarded as a runtime implementation detail. (Copying large lazily-evaluated values can be very inefficient, though, so in practice captures are implemented "by-reference")

At the semantic level, Haskell doesn't "capture variables". It just provides language features that let you define new functions, which may happen to use variables as part of their definition (in exactly the same way as let x = a + b can define a new Integer x in terms of the variables a, b, and +). Making that work is the language implementer's problem, for Haskell. C++ doesn't give you that as a basic feature, so when you want something like that you're responsible for understanding what the runtime does and implementing it correctly in terms of the features it does have.

If you're thinking about closures, variable capture, whether things are references or values, those are all fairly advanced implementation details in Haskell, not what you think about as basics. They're interesting details, and even useful when you need to really optimise performance. So no objection to anyone asking about them. But you don't need to know them to program in Haskell, and if you're learning I'd recommend learning the basic high level model and then building up initiation for how it translates into the lower level concepts.

GHC captures variables in the closure by reference, but (1) because all values are allocated on a garbage collected heap, the reference remains valid for the lifetime of the closure, so there will be no runtime error as in your C++ example; and (2) because Haskell values are immutable, the behavior of the program is basically the same as if the closure had been captured by value, since the values of references don't change over the lifetime of Haskell programs.
So, for example, in the program:
subtracter :: Integer -> (Integer -> Integer)
subtracter delta = let increment = -delta in \x -> x + increment

the result of a call subtracter 42 is a lambda x -> x + increment that has captured the value of increment by reference.  Even though increment was a "local variable" (or as close as one gets to a local variable in Haskell), it is still a reference is to an immutable value -42 on the heap, not a mutable value on the stack, as it would be with C++.  So, the reference will remain valid for the lifetime of the lambda, and it will always be an immutable reference to the value -42, so the effect is the same as if the lambda had captured it "by value" as -42.
